# Maintaining state in distributed application

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, distributed, celluloid

I am creating an asynchronous application using zeromq, celluloid. I need to maintain the states for different tasks that depend on some response. I can do it by sending data about the state in the response params. But is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

### Use uniquely identified `Conditions` to wait for replies.

The question is very abstract/vague, so I will do the best I can to give you a functional example. If I understand/guess correctly, this is what you need to do:

1. Generate a `UUID` with `Celluloid::Internals::UUID.generate` before the request is made.
2. Package the request data, and send the `UUID` with the data.
3. Create a `Condition`, associated with that `UUID`.
4. Send the request.
5. Process the request, keeping the `UUID` associated with it.
6. Return the response, sending the `UUID` back with the reply data.
7. Process the response on a generic ( non-stated ) level... then signal the `Condition` with the data returned, locating the `Condition` in a thread-safe `Hash` by `UUID`.
8. Receive the data you needed *within* the stated object, by blocking at `wait` in that stated object... rather than processing the response directly.

The stated object ought to have no awareness of `0MQ` which is by design stateless... it ought to communicate with a layer which makes requests, receives responses, and delivers the response to the object who asked for it, without that stated object losing its state, and without the state information being passed in the request or the response.

---

This strategy is used heavily by [`ECell`](https://github.com/celluloid/ecell) which is forthcoming. Hopefully you are already using the [`celluloid-zmq`](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid-zmq) gem for evented `0MQ` support already.